# My program needs to filll all of the criterias instead of choose how many criteria that the user want

Tags: php, laravel

I have this kind of program that calculate the values based on the criteria

```
$students = DB::table('ar_student_score')->get();
                foreach ($students as $key=>$student) {
                    $finalscore = ($weight['Score']!=''? $student->student_score * $weight['Score'] : $student->student_score*0) + ($weight['Achievement']!=''? $student->student_achv_score * $weight['Achievement'] : $student->student_achv_score * 0)+ ($weight['Attendance']==''? $student->student_attend_score * $weight['Attendance'] : $student->student_attend_score *0) + ($weight['Behaviour']==''? $student->student_behaviour_score * $weight['Behaviour']:$student->student_behaviour_score *0);
                    $ranking[$key]['name']=$student->student_name;
                    $ranking[$key]['finalscore']=$finalscore;
                }
                $ranking = collect($ranking)->sortBy('finalscore')->reverse()->toArray();
                return view('AHP_RamaAlvin.DSS', compact('progressAHP'), compact('criteria'))->with('chartData', $chartData)->with('ranking',$ranking);
```

The problem is it requires all of the criteria to be filled but in my program the user can choose how many criteria that they want to fill. Any idea how to solve this? If the user not filled all the criteria, the error will be like missing achievement criteria. I tried to changed it into this

```
$students = DB::table('ar_student_score')->get();
                foreach ($students as $key=>$student) {
                    for($i=0;$i<$numofcriteria;$i++){
                        $finalscore+= $weight[$data['criteria'][$i]]*$student->$data['criteria'][$i];
                    }
                    $ranking[$key]['name']=$student->student_name;
                    $ranking[$key]['finalscore']=$finalscore;
                }
                $ranking = collect($ranking)->sortBy('finalscore')->reverse()->toArray();
                return view('AHP_RamaAlvin.DSS', compact('progressAHP'), compact('criteria'))->with('chartData', $chartData)->with('ranking',$ranking);
```

but it gives error " Array to String conversion"

Comment: What is your PHP version ? If you are at PHP7+ , you can use the coalesce operator `??`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in a controller, you could extract a score method

```
public function score($student, $weightMap)
{
    $score = 0;
    foreach($weightMap as $critera => $weight)
    {
        $score += $student->$criteria * $weight;
    }

    return $score;

}
```

The score method could accept an associative array with optional criterias

```
$finalScore = $this->score(
    $student,
    ['student_attend_score' => 0.2, 'student_score' => 0.8,]
)
```

To keep it simpler you could rename them to match the key they are refering to on on `student`, eg rename `Achievement`  to `student_achv_score`.